# How to retrieve multiple images from mysql to imagelist in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I want to retrieve multiple images from a MySQL database to be added to image list collection when my form has loaded.

What I have tried within form load event:

```
cn.Open()
  Using cmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl_products", cn)
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    Dim dt_images As New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt_images)
    For Each dr As DataRow In dt_images.Rows
      Dim img_buffer = CType(dr("IMAGE"), Byte())

      Dim img_stream As New MemoryStream(img_buffer, True)

      img_stream.Write(img_buffer, 0, img_buffer.Length)
      imglist.Images.Add(dr("image").ToString(), New Bitmap(img_stream))
      img_stream.Close()
    Next
  End Using
cn.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Using connection As New MySqlConnection("connection string here"),
      command As New MySqlCommand("SELECT image FROM tbl_products", connection)
    connection.Open()

    Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
            Using stream As New MemoryStream(DirectCast(reader("image"), Byte()))
                imglist.Images.Add(Image.FromStream(stream))
            End Using
        End While
    End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

First, as shown in your code the column that stores images is named (IMAGE)
it must have a Data type of OLE Object

Second, in this line:

```
imglist.Images.Add(dr("image").ToString(), New Bitmap(img_stream))
```

dr("image") is the image key string not image containg column
so i suggest you create a new column in Database named for example (RankID)
which has (autonumber) datatype, then changes this line to:

```
imglist.Images.Add(dr("RankID").ToString(), New Bitmap(img_stream))
```

Finally, You are Just adding images to imagelist, you need a listview to show it.
create a new listview (listview1) then add these lines inside your for each loop:

```
Dim isvparent As New ListViewItem
isvparent.ImageKey = myrow("RankID")
ListView1.Items.Add(isvparent)
```